# jquery function conflict and return error when load another php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following working sample application that display typing text in a terminal window:

## Step 1 - working sample which has no problem (3 files in one folder: `index.php`, `style.css` and `typed-custom.js`)

I have the following content for `style.css`:

```
 .terminal-window {
  text-align: left;
  width: 620px;
  height: 650px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.terminal-window section.terminal {
  color: white;
  font-family: Menlo, Monaco, "Consolas", "Courier New", "Courier";
  font-size: 11pt;
  background: black;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 30px;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
.term-home{color: #0095ff;}
```

I have the following content for `typed-custom.js`

```
$(function() {
  var data = [

  {
    action: 'type',
    strings: ["typing-1:"],
    output: '<span class="green"><small> This is first typing</small></span>&nbsp;',
    postDelay: 1000,
  },

  {
    action: 'type',
    strings: ["typing-2:"],
    output: '<span class="green"><small>This is second typing</small></span>&nbsp;',
    postDelay: 1000
  },

  ];
  runScripts(data, 0);
});

function runScripts(data, pos) {
    var prompt = $('.prompt'),
        script = data[pos];
    if(script.clear === true) {
      $('.history').html('');
    }
    switch(script.action) {
        case 'type':
          // cleanup for next execution
          prompt.removeData();
          $('.typed-cursor').text('');
          prompt.typed({
            strings: script.strings,
            typeSpeed: 10,
            callback: function() {
              var history = $('.history').html();
              history = history ? [history] : [];
              history.push('<span class="term-home">root:~$</span> ' + prompt.text());
              if(script.output) {
                history.push(script.output);
                prompt.html('');
                $('.history').html(history.join('<br>'));
              }
              // scroll to bottom of screen
              $('section.terminal').scrollTop($('section.terminal').height());
              // Run next script
              pos++;
              if(pos < data.length) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                  runScripts(data, pos);
                                  }, script.postDelay || 1000);
              }
            }
          });
          break;
        case 'view':

          break;
    }
}

//Note: `typed-custom.js` depends on the library from `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/1.1.1/typed.min.js` which I have included in index.php:
```

For displaying, I have the following content for `index.php`

```
<?php
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>Test load (load.php)</title>
    <!-- Get jQuery -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/1.1.1/typed.min.js"></script>
    <script src="typed-custom.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

    <!-- terminal -->
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="title-head"> <h5><font color="white">Test</font></h5></div>
        <div class="type-wrap">
            <div class="terminal-window">
                <header>
                    <div class="button green"></div>
                    <div class="button yellow"></div>
                    <div class="button red"></div>
                    <div class="button black"></div>
                </header>
               <section class="terminal">
                    <div class="history"></div>
                    <span class="term-home">root:~$</span>&nbsp;<span class="prompt"></span>
                    <span class="typed-cursor"></span>
                </section>
            <!-- data -->
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The above is working perfectly with no error.

## Step 2 - the problem when loaded external php `load.php` file into `index.php`

but now I want to add another display from a php page, so I created a php file call `load.php` with the following content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>load.php show data</title>
 <style>
        .loadData div {display:none;}
        .loadData div.display {display: block;}
 </style>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="loadData">
    <div>Content 1</div>
    <div>Content 2</div>
    <div>Content 3</div>
    <div>Content 4</div>
    <div>Content 5</div>
</div>

<a href="#" id="loadMore">Load More</a>

<script>
// this code is used to reduce long div display. example 5 div, reduce it to 3 and when click Load More, it will show all.
$(function () {
    $(".loadData div").slice(0, 3).addClass('display');
    $("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".loadData div:hidden").addClass('display');
        if ($(".loadData div:hidden").length == 0) {
           $("#loadMore").remove();
        } else {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
            }, 1500);
        }
    });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then, I updated my index.php just to load the file `load.php` at the bottom like this:

`index.php`

```
<?php
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>Test Terminal with another php file load at the bottom (load.php)</title>
    <!-- Get jQuery -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/1.1.1/typed.min.js"></script>
    <script src="typed-custom.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
        <!-- internal style -->
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- terminal -->
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="title-head"> <h5><font color="white">Test</font></h5></div>
        <div class="type-wrap">
            <div class="terminal-window">
                <header>
                    <div class="button green"></div>
                    <div class="button yellow"></div>
                    <div class="button red"></div>
                    <div class="button black"></div>
                </header>
               <section class="terminal">
                    <div class="history"></div>
                    <span class="term-home">root:~$</span>&nbsp;<span class="prompt"></span>
                    <span class="typed-cursor"></span>
                </section>
            <!-- data -->
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
<!-- NEW CODE HERE WHICH HAS ERROR: try to load an external file using js -->
<div class="container"></div>
<div> This index.php loads "load.php" below</div>
<div id="contents"></div>
<div> ----------------------- </div>
<script>
 $().ready(function() {
        $("#contents").load("load.php");

 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

but, when I run the above code, I got an error saying:

```
typed-custom.js:39 Uncaught TypeError: prompt.typed is not a function
    at runScripts (typed-custom.js:39)
    at typed-custom.js:57
```

and my terminal window stopped typing for the 2nd text (which I suspect is js conflict) but there is no problem clicking the 'Load More' button which also uses js to call.

Error screenshot: [image: This is the error in visual]

I searched this error and it said that I might have jquery conflict, but I'm not sure which part is the conflict. Any idea?

Comment: Please try and reduce the amount of code you have in your question.  It can be useful to show how you got to the current problem, but for most questions it is only relevant to show the current code needed to reproduce the error.

Comment: My aim is for somebody to run this working sample with great visual.  I will check, and try to reduce it.

Comment: Hi, I have reduced the code, and the problem starts in `step 2`. the `step 1`  is only for demonstration a working sample application.

Comment: There is a problem with `typed-custom.js` so where is the code from this file?

Comment: @Coli the `typed-custom.js` I already added in the `step 1` and it depends on the library from this: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/1.1.1/typed.min.js"></script>` which i have included in index.php

Comment: If I don't load the php page, there is no error. The problem is when I load the external php file called `load.php` into `index.php` as shown in my example `step 2`.

Comment: @Coli May I know what is the problem with typed-custom.js that you have mentioned ? because that is what the debugger told. but I think, this is more like js conflict. Maybe if somebody could guide me, how to avoid the conflict in this structure of code. Because I'm not sure what to change since index.php is trying to load another php file called load.php which also has jquery loaded.

Comment: if load.php is intended to be inserted within index.php then it should not have its own html, head and body tags, and shouldn't declare its own version of jQuery. Ideally it shouldn't contain any javascript code of its own either (that should be in separate JS files), it should just be a fragment of HTML which is going to be injected into the main page. Loading a whole new separate HTML document (as denoted by the html/head/body tags) inside another HTML document doesn't make any sense. And loading jQuery twice isn't needed - the browser only needs one copy at a time.

Comment: Also...you're just adding "load.php" to the page as soon as index.php has finished loading. If that's really what you want, then why not just include it via PHP's `include` command - that way it's sent to the browser at the same time as index.php and doesn't need to be fetched separately. That would be more efficient and less error-prone.

Comment: The only reason for using js file in load.php is I want to have that link Load More to show hidden <div> which I think only possible using js. The load.php actually has more than the one that I gave example, For example it fetches data from another website and do many other js functions. So, I think I need js in there. I tried include command but it still breaks the js because the problem is the load.php has js.

Comment: Sure but "load more" is part of load.php. So it's only when someone clicks on "load more" that you need to run some JS. The original "load.php" can be included via PHP - yes `include('load.php');` would be the general idea.

Comment: "it still breaks the js because the problem is the load.php has js."...not sure what you mean. You'd have to give specific details of error messages etc. Like I said, load.php doesn't need to add another copy of jQuery - have you removed it?

Comment: allright it's working! Thanks a lot. can u write the answer and I will accept it. Since it's a good idea to have a question with an answer. no need answer from the code. just what u wrote here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If load.php is intended to be inserted within index.php then it should not have its own html, head and body tags. It should just be a fragment of HTML which is going to be injected into the main page. Loading a whole new separate HTML document (as denoted by the html/head/body tags) inside another HTML document doesn't make any sense.

Also...you're just adding "load.php" to the page as soon as index.php has finished loading. Instead you can just include it via PHP's `include` command - that way it's sent to the browser at the same time as index.php and doesn't need to be fetched separately. That would be more efficient and less error-prone.

And load.php doesn't need to add another copy of jQuery, so you can remove that - it can cause conflicts or unexpected behaviour. The browser sees both files as being part of a single page, so it only needs a single copy of jQuery.